# react and react native : is uuid react package supports mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react  uuid react package in my react app and I am using react native starter kit.  My question is that is uuid  supports mobile development also ?
please explain thanks..

this is the uuid package link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

this is the starter kit which I am using 
https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-kit

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn add uuid
```

You can use it as below

```js
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

console.log("UUID: ", uuidv1());
```

Try below code in your screen.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
console.log("UUID: ", uuidv1());

// Remaining Code
```

Comment: will it support mobile development also ?

Comment: Yes, we are using in react native app.

Comment: I tried this but  is it only work ofr mobile browser or mobile app also ?

Comment: hi is this only for react native, actually my code is universal its for react and react-native both, will this solution work for it ?

Comment: My code is only for react native. I am not sure if it will work with react.

Comment: so you are sure that this packge works for react native ?  https://github.com/mcnamee/react-native-starter-kit

Comment: This package is also working with react-native-starter kit.

Comment: you should install like this:     yarn add uuid

Comment: const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

console.log("UUIDV1", uuidv1())